# How can I get all my ZTE 830's stuff to HTC without using a computer?

Tags: backup, data-recovery, broken-screen

My old ZTE 830 has a shattered screen and I just bought a new HTC. How can I transfer my ZTE phone's data into my new HTC mobile. I do not have a computer to hook in too.

Comment: Can you see any content on the screen? I'm not saying you can touch but only about seeing it. If you can then try connecting a mouse (can be arranged compared to a computer) if the device supports OTG. A lot of content can be transferred using ADB. Anyhow, what is the device name? There are many Q/A under the tag [tag:broken-screen]. Have a look at them.

Comment: I have no computer to plug it in to any it's a ZTE model 830. It's turns on but that is it. I'm still getting texts on it that I can't see. I bought a new HTC cause I was told I could use it to see all my info on other phone thru new one.

Comment: Without a computer chances are tough, but existent. As that's a frequent question here, we've set up some first-aid in the [broken-screen tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/broken-screen/info) (our [data-recovery tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/data-recovery/info) might be worth a look as well). Short hints: Connect to TV via HDMI, and connect a USB keyboard/mouse as well. That way you should be able to see what you're doing, and use mouse/keyboard to act.